# yii2 use dblib driver SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Invalid object name t_user

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

I have use dblib driver in my project ,
but execute  query exception

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Invalid object name 't_user'. [20018] (severity 16) [select top 10 * from t_user]
The SQL being executed was: select top 10 * from t_user
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 20018
    [2] => Invalid object name 't_user'. [20018] (severity 16) [select top 10 * from t_user]
    [3] => -1
    [4] => 16
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Invalid object name 't_user'. [20018] (severity 16) [select top 10 * from t_user]
```

If I use native PHP, it's OK

```
<?php

 $dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=;dbname=","","");

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT top 1 * from t_user");
$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetch()){
        print_r($row);
}
```

I install freetds php_dblib

The configuration information

```
➜  www /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.1.40/bin/tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.1.40
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 7.3
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
                            OpenSSL: yes
                             GnuTLS: no
                               MARS: yes
➜  www php -v
PHP 7.3.18 (cli) (built: May 29 2020 02:17:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.18, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
➜  www php -m | grep dblib
pdo_dblib
➜  www php --ri pdo_dblib

pdo_dblib

PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib => enabled
Flavour => freetds
```

the yii2 config  [ use yii2 basic 2.0.x]

```
 <?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection', // yii connection
    'dsn' => 'dblib:host=;database=', // this is dblib
    'username' => '', // user name 
    'password' => '', // password
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I don't know how to tackle this problem。
Ask for help, Daniel~

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: could you please try instead of select top 10* from user use select top 10* from dbo.user

Comment: Also, `USER` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, "user" is a reserved word. Using reserved words as identifiers is a bad idea - and you really need to develop good habits not more bad ones.

You SHOULD change the name of your table so that it does not need to be delimited. Learn by by reading the documentation for [regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15). But you can use the following:

```
select <columns of interest> from dbo.[user] order by <whatever>:
```

Note the good habits - schema-qualify object names, specify the columns you need, apply an ORDER BY clause if needed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with dbo. I'm just an example. Now any query will prompt an error